# lights taken out cant figure out how to rewire

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

My dad took down two fixtures in the basement that were working fine just before he took them out (one died). He didn't take a picture of the wiring before taking them out. Now we can't figure out how to wire the switch in.

The furthest light away from the switch has three wire power in (white, black, red, and earth). There is three wire out from there and into the next light fixture and two out to a wall socket. The switch isn't connected to the wall socket and I can't find a connection with a multi-meter in ohms in any configuration of wires.

Comment: With the breaker still off, take a picture of the wiring inside the switch box, then pull the outlet (but do NOT disconnect anything) and take a picture of that, then pull the light fixtures and take pictures of the wiring there. [Edit] these into your post (just drag the images in, the site will upload & host them for you), and you'll get a better answer.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the switch and light fixture boxes please?

Comment: Any pics, @andrew H?

Answer (score 0):

Buy a tester and bell out your cables find the permanent feed and neutral then find your switch live not sure how americans wire you lights usually here in the uk we send a permanent feed and neutral and a switch live to the lights

Comment: Sounds like you've got a lot of experience and know what you're talking about. Unfortunately, many (or even most) people who ask questions here haven't a clue what they're talking about and phrases like "a tester" and "bell out" are going to be meaningless technobabble. Please explain these tools and processes so a complete novice can understand them - that will add a _lot_ to your answer. (At a minimum, provide links to what kind of "tester" and a description of what "bell out" is and how one does it.)

Comment: OP already said they used a multimeter set to ohms, so they're looking for continuity and that's more than some would have thought to do. Belling out refers to continuity testing anyway. Agreed with comments on the OP, we need to see pictures.